# Select value from mysql table when field equal to many values

Tags: mysql

I have simple mysql table with 2 fields:

```
atr_id | atr_val_id
1      | 100
1      | 200
1      | 300
2      | 100
3      | 100
3      | 200
4      | 200
```

How can I select for example all atr_ids values that have atr_val_id = 100 AND 200 and nothing more ? This will be only atr_id = 3 in that example.
Or for example only 200, this will be atr_id = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be be simpler ways to do. Here goes one solution that uses mix of group by, group_contact, distinct, sort and having clause to fetch your desired result

All atr_ids values that have atr_val_id = 100 AND 200 and nothing more. This will return only atr_id = 3

```
select 
    atr_id 
from 
    tbl_test
group by 
    atr_id
having 
    group_concat(distinct atr_val_id order by atr_val_id asc) = '100,200'
```

and for only 200, this will return atr_id = 4

```
select 
    atr_id 
from 
    tbl_test
group by 
    atr_id
having 
    group_concat(distinct atr_val_id order by atr_val_id asc) = '200'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Im just wondering what if I have thousands of records, isn't the group_concat function too slow?

Comment: No, its not slow even on hundred thousand records if your db is properly indexed :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the NOT EXISTS as below

```
select atr_id 
from table_name t1 
where atr_val_id in(100,200)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  select 1
  from table_name t2
  where t2.atr_id = t1.atr_id
  group by t2.atr_id
  having count(t2.atr_val_id) < 2 OR count(t2.atr_val_id) > 2 

)
group by t1.atr_id
;
```

You can change the count part depending on the number of atr_val_id you are looking at. Say for just 200 its going to be

```
having count(t2.atr_val_id) < 1 OR count(t2.atr_val_id) > 1
```

And subsequently you need to change the IN clause as well.

Comment: This would return the case of two atr_val_id=100 or atr_val_id=200 entries.